# Updating class variable or calling class function from member variable is giving runtime error

Tags: c++, oop, c++11

I am trying to implement update which will update to all the listerner classes
I am using class variable to count number of listeners.
**MyClass** 's are extending listener to listen from the **updater** class

I am getting runtime error when I am trying to update class variable with class function from member function. Please refer below code and help me out sorting this problem

```
 #define MAX_LISTNERS 10
class Listner{
public: 
virtual void onUpdate() = 0;
};
class Updater {
    Listner* ptrListner[MAX_LISTNERS];
    static int count;
    public: 
     static void updateCount(){
        count++;
    }
    void registerListner(Listner* ptrListner){
        this->ptrListner[count] = ptrListner;
        this->updateCount(); //---> Runtime Error
    }
    void updateToListner(){
        for(int i=0;i<=count;i++){
        this->ptrListner[i]->onUpdate();
        }
    }
};
 int  Updater::count = 0;
class MyClass: public Listner{
    public:
     void onUpdate(){
        cout<<"update from MyClass";
     }
};  
class MyClass2: public Listner{
    public:
     void onUpdate(){
        cout<<"update from MyClass2";
     }};
int main() {
    MyClass* obj = new MyClass();
    MyClass2* obj2 = new MyClass2();
    Updater obj_updater;
    obj_updater.registerListner(dynamic_cast<Listner*>(obj));
    obj_updater.registerListner(dynamic_cast<Listner*>(obj2));
    obj_updater.updateToListner();
}
```

Comment: The `updateToListener` function will go outside the range of initialized elements in `ptrListener`.

Comment: Not a problem in this example, but having a static `count` will create holes in the array if you ever have more than one `Updater`.

Comment: The code is throwing runtime error

Comment: Oh and that `dynamic_cast` is not needed.

Answer (score 1):

A few things to consider here as this seems all a bit unsafe and not up to the modern C++11 way.

1. Use RAII for your allocations, i.e. unique_ptr instead of explicit new/delete
2. Use std::vector instead of a C-Style array declaration. You can limit the amount during runtime. This also gives you implicit listener count
3. Let the Updater class take care of allocation, factory style which also allows you to respect type safety

Something like the following:

```
class Listner
{
    public:
        virtual void onUpdate() = 0;
};

class Updater
{
    using ListnerPtr = std::unique_ptr<Listner>;
    using Listners   = std::vector<ListnerPtr>;

    Listners m_listeners;

public:
    template < typename T >
    bool registerListner()
    {
        static_assert(std::is_base_of<Listner, T>::value, "T must be derived from Listner");

        if (m_listeners.size() >= 10)
            return false;

        m_listeners.emplace_back(std::make_unique<T>());
        return true;
    }

    void updateToListner()
    {
        std::for_each(m_listeners.begin(), m_listeners.end(), [](const Listners::value_type& item)
        {
            item->onUpdate();
        });
    }
};

class MyClass : public Listner
{
public:
    void onUpdate() override
    {
        std::cout << "update from MyClass" << std::endl;
    }
};

class MyClass2 : public Listner
{
public:
    void onUpdate() override
    {
        std::cout << "update from MyClass2" << std::endl;
    }
};

int main
{
    Updater obj_updater;
    obj_updater.registerListner<MyClass>();
    obj_updater.registerListner<MyClass2>();
    obj_updater.updateToListner();
    return 0
}
```